# Xcode shows two pods directory. How to remove one directory

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a project which shows two pods directory. I don't know if it has some kind of cons and how did it happen. Can Anyone please tell me how to remove one pod directory. These two directories are identical.

[image: Pod Screenshot]

[image: Another Screenshot]

Project's POD file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do

    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for MyProject
    #For Keyboard Resigning
    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

    #For Activity Controller
    pod 'EZLoadingActivity'

    #For API manager
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'

    #for chat
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'

    pod 'Instructions', '~> 1.0.0'

    #For Video calling
    pod 'SinchRTC'
    #for photos
    pod 'SKPhotoBrowser'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'

    #For Permissions
    pod 'Permission'
    #For Rating with stars
    pod 'FloatRatingView', '~> 2.0.0'

   #For Photo Editor
   pod 'CLImageEditor/AllTools'

   #For Facebook Login
   pod 'FacebookCore'
   pod 'FacebookLogin'
   pod 'FacebookShare'

   #For Google TranslationMethods
   pod "ROGoogleTranslate"

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the use_frameworks! above target

```
 use_frameworks!

 target 'MyProject' do

   pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'

 end
```

Comment: I did and after that, i hit pod install. but it still shows two directories

Comment: remove one target from project settings and re run

Comment: Kinda new to this. can you tell me precisely where to go :D

Comment: I deleted both directories and then did a clean pod install. project is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Check in your Project folder if Pods folder exist once or twice. If it exists twice then remove one, if not remove one Pods from project by choosing "remove reference'. Good luck.

Comment: Thank , when i deleted one other becomes invalid. so I had to remove both of the pod directory and do a clean pod install